# How to apply jQuery plugin to multiple divs on same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a jQuery plugin and I need it to work on multiple divs on one page. Basically, I have two menus and when a user clicks on one menu item the background color changes. Right now, the effect is being applied to both menus instead of individually. For example, if I click on item one of menu one the background changes but if I click on item two of menu two, the background of item one menu one is removed while the background of item 2 menu 2 changes.

I need for the menus to be completely separate from each other. Clicking on menu one should not change menu two. Here is how the plugin is set up so far:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.selectBox = function () {
        function get() {
            $('.ms-section-select li').first().addClass('ms-checked');
        }

        function get() {
            $('.ms-section-select li').click(function () {
                $('.ms-section-select li').removeClass('ms-checked');
                $(this).addClass('ms-checked');
            });
        }
        return this.each(get);
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.one').selectBox();
$('.two').selectBox();
```

Here is a jsfiddle example with all of the code http://jsfiddle.net/977hv/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to apply the change on only the siblings of the selected element 
Is this what you are trying to do?
http://jsfiddle.net/977hv/8/

```
$(this).siblings('.ms-section-select li').removeClass('ms-checked');
```

To apply it to the first child

```
    $('.ms-section-select li:first-child').addClass('ms-checked');
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need, thanks! That method actually only helps out that one function though. The first function still isn't being applied to each individual menu.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the first function?
Are you trying to select first elements for both lists by default?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. At page load, each of the first boxes ("all") should have the light gray background.

Comment: Check the edited answer
THe jquery.first() selector selects the first element of that type 
You need to use the first-child css selector to apply on first child of all lists
Also your first get() function was over ridden by the second
Also you need to select the first elements only the first time so you can do that without a function

Answer (score 1):

```
function selectBox () { 

    $('.ms-section-select li').on('click', function(){
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('ms-checked');
        $(this).addClass('ms-checked');

    })
};

selectBox();
```

this should do the trick - check: http://jsfiddle.net/977hv/6/